# Page Length not showing when adding Excel button in datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable

When i added excel button in data table the page length selection option disappeared.

Language : C#
VisualStudio: 15.9.24

```
  Initalize Data Table 
    $(".datatable").dataTable({
            language: {
                search: "<span>Filter:</span> INPUT",
                searchPlaceholder: "Type to filter...",
                lengthMenu: "<span>Show:</span> MENU",
                paginate: { "first": "First", "last": "Last", "next": $("html").attr("dir") == "rtl" ? "&larr;" : "&rarr;", "previous": $("html").attr("dir") == "rtl" ? "&rarr;" : "&larr;" }  
            },
            "autoWidth": false,
    dom: "Bfrtip",
        
        buttons: [{ extend: "excelHtml5",
        exportOptions: { 
        columns: [0,1,2]},
        footer: true }] 
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace dom: "Blfrtip" in place dom: "Bfrtip",